# ConTeXt TABLEs width

Tags: tables, context

I am using the "[natural tables](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE)" in ConTeXt:

```
\bTABLE
\bTR \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD 2 \eTD \bTD 3 \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
```

How can I setup the table that the whole table uses a certain width? For example `width=\textwidth`

Comment: If you are going to ask difficult questions, you have to ensure that Wolfgang Schuster reads this forum :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\bTABLE[width=broad,autowidth=no]`

or

`\bTABLE[option=stretch]`

Comment: It works, but somehow it does not take `\startnarrower`... `\stopnarrower` into account. Do you have any idea?